# Why does ServiceStack default Html Snapshot view show the date using DateTime.UtcNow?

Tags: datetime, servicestack, utc

When I view my ServiceStack endpoints through a browser, I get the very helpful snapshot of the data in a convenient HTML table.  The title looks something like this:

`Snapshot of EndPoint generated by ServiceStack on DateTime`

The `DateTime` shown seems to be in `UTC` format and I'm trying to work out why.  In the UK now it is British Summer Time (UTC +1) so ServiceStack always shows the wrong time for this.

The source code is here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Formats/HtmlFormat.cs#L63

My question is:

**Is this is a minor bug or is there another reason I am not aware of for displaying the date and time in UTC?**

Comment: Why is it the "wrong time"? :-)

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I'm not sure I follow.  It's the wrong time because it is displaying UTC, which is not the correct time for my timezone (BST).  Eg. it displays 11:43:59 when it is actually 12:43:59.

Comment: It's not wrong because that *is* the time in UTC. It should either be explicit about that (easy) or display it in the timezone of the browser user (actually a bit harder).

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thanks for your response.  I agree that it is displaying the correct time in UTC, but the purpose of this DateTime is to display the time to the user.  Therefore, I think, it should be shown in their timezone.  If this is not possible, I think the correct DateTime on the server would be better than UTC.  The purpose of this page is for developer consumption, therefore I think server time (DateTime.Now) is better than UTC time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates always travel on the wire as UTC, the purpose of [ServiceStack's HTML5 Report Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat) is to display the data from the web service in a human friendly format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Demis.  I understand what you're saying, but in my mind the purpose of the HTML5 Report Page is to make developers lives easier.  In my case I am using the response caching feature ToOptimizedResultUsingCache, so I am interested in the Date/Time that the request was cached by the server.  I don't really follow why showing UTC is useful.  I end up doing the calculation in my head every time I send a request.  For me, it certainly would be easier if it displayed my current time.  I'm not trying to be argumentative, just want to learn more!  I appreciate you helping me.

Comment: Its helpful because "UTC on the Wire" is a blanket rule that you can rely on that remains consistent throughout ServiceStack. The date doesn't change where ever in the world you see it, it always stays as UTC.